# Prove that if $n/m$ is even then $\gcd(2^m+1,2^n+1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $m,n\in \mathbb N$ , such that $m\mid n$. show that if $\frac{n}{m}$ is even then $\gcd(2^m+1,2^n+1)=1$

**My attempt:**

I took $n=14$ and $m=7$

$$\gcd(2^n+1,2^m+1)=\gcd(2^{14}+1,2^{7}+1)=\gcd(16385,129)=1$$

How can I prove that, hints ?

Comment: try to calculate it without using a calculator

Comment: Why should I do that

Comment: Because: If you need a calculator you (almost) surely on the wrong track with regards to making a proof.

Comment: @Henrik, that is not necessarily true.

Comment: maybe you get an idea how to prove your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(2^m+1)(2^m-1)=2^{2m}-1 $$

Answer (score 3):

Since $n/m$ is even, there exists an even number $k$ with $km=n$.

Denote $d:=\gcd(2^m+1,2^n+1).$

We have $$2^m\equiv -1\pmod d$$

and $$2^n=2^{mk}=(2^m)^k\equiv (-1)^k=1\pmod d$$

So, $2^n\equiv 2^m\equiv -1$ modulo $d$ implies $2\equiv 0$ modulo $d$, so we have
$d|2$,

and therefore $d=1$ or $d=2$.

But $2^m+1$ is odd (because for $m=0$, $n/m$ would be undefined) , so $d$ must be $1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the consense that the OP should show some effort, which is in general a good consense, leads to the death of many interesting questions, puzzles and so on, just because the OP does not show enough effort in the view of some voters. In the worst case, the answer is closed or even deleted. Next time you ask a question like this, just show some more examples, this might avoid a downvote-flood. And for the future : Do not demand upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\gcd(2^{14}+1,2^{7}+1)=\gcd((2^{14}+1)-2^7(2^{7}+1)),2^{7}+1)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume p/2^m+1.    2^(2mk)+1 = (2^m+1-1)^2k +1= (pd-1)^2k+1. Reducing mod p gives 2 which can be 0 only when p is 1.

Comment: This draws some ideas from Peter's answer.